# Can't find background image

Tags: background-image

I might be a bit dumb or something, but I just can't find the background image of the site:

http://www.deineschatzkammer.com

Can anyone find it or tell me how to find it easily? I have searched now with the Chrome DevTools and Firebug and searched the code for GIFs, JPGs and PNGs... :(

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to set a background image, some in HTML and some in CSS. Though the most common case is to use the `background-image` CSS property.

In most cases, background images covering the whole page are set on the `<body>` or `<html>` element. So you should check those first via the DevTools' *Elements* / *Inspector* panel.

If they don't include the image or the image only covers a part of the page, you should follow these steps to find out where the image is:

1. Right-click the image and choose *Inspect* from the context menu. This opens up the DevTools and selects the right-clicked element withi the *Elements* / *Inspector* panel.
2. Check whether the inspected element is an image element (might be an `<img>`, `<picture>` or another media element) containing the searched image.
3. If it is not an image element or not the one you're searching for, look at its CSS styles. Check whether one of the rules contains a `background-image` property.
4. If there isn't a `background-image` property containing the related image, this means the element containing the image is overlayed by the one you just inspected. So delete the element by pressing <kbd>Del</kbd> on the selected element via the context menu.
5. Repeat step 1.

In case there's a small number of images on the page, you may also search within the Network panel. To do that you should first filter by images and then go through the different image requests.